# Algebraically closedness on a theorem of Hartshorne.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

The following theorem is from Hartshorne's book on ample subvarieties:

Some definitions:

[image]

[image]

The theorem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is Corollary 1.2:

[image]

This is prop 1.3: (The proof of this one is very long not sure if I can copy paste pages of proof here)

[image]

Hartshorne always assumes he is working on algebraically closed fields and sometimes the assumption is not necessary. I was wondering whether this result is true if we drop the assumption that we are working on an algebraically closed field or not? I wasn't able to find where it is used exactly but it could be implicit somewhere. If true without the algebraically closed-ness I wonder whether there is a reference for it?

Comment: 1. What is "Leff" in the final line? 2. If you can post the proof, it would give more people a shot at answering the question. For instance, if a Bertini-type theorem is a big ingredient in the proof, there's a fair amount of literature about when those sorts of theorems hold in the non-algebraically-closed case, and someone with knowledge of that but not your proof could be helpful.

Comment: I'll provide a complete definition and proof.

Comment: I am more interested over finite fields which a Bertini type theorem is true.

Comment: The first place to start with Bertini theorems over finite fields is probably [Poonen's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204002.pdf), though the specifics of your questions about Bertini over finite fields is likely worthy of a disjoint post.